# Stop hooks re-fetching data on component update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react hooks and as i read in docs useEffect runs on every update of component and on first render also (so it is `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` combined) but when i am fetching data inside useEffect it will re-do it when state updates and so if I set state value after fetching data from server it will create infinite loop. and i want to prevent it and only fetch it for first render like in `componentDidMount`, how can i implement this?

Comment: Can you share your code? normally you pass an array to `useEffect` in a way that prevents infinite loops.

Comment: yeah thanks, passing array worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect()` takes a dependencies as an array parameter. This dependency(ies) acts as a decider such that, if one of the dependencies' value change, useEffect is invoked.

It's effectively equivalent to saying:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
 // If props or state changes, update the component
 if(this.props.someProp != nextProps.someProp  || this.state.someState != nextState.someState){
   return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

**With useEffect() :**

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Do stuff here
}, [somePropValue, someStateValue]);
```

But to say that only do once, specify an empty dependency array(ideal for API calls that happens once on load):

```
useEffect(() => {
      //Do stuff here
    }, []);
```